# Node Script Throwing Strange code ELIFECYCLE errno 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, jshint

In an effort to remove gulp from my project, I'm refactoring all of my scripts into node scripts. This has been largely successful, however, in refactoring my JSHint scripts, I'm running into a peculiar (though largely benign) problem. My script in package.json is:

`"jshint-script": "jshint --reporter=tasks/misc_tasks/jshint.js build/ --exclude build-/libs/"`

This works absolutely fine when I type it directly into the command line. However, when I run `npm run jshint-script`, everything runs just fine, but then an error is blown.

`npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! Rosetta@5.0.0 jshint-script:`jshint --reporter=tasks/misc_tasks/reporter.js build-ts/ --exclude build/libs/
`npm ERR! Exit status 2`

the full log is below:

`0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'jshint' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prejshint', 'jshint', 'postjshint' ]
5 info lifecycle Project@5.0.0~prejshint: Project@5.0.0
6 info lifecycle Project@5.0.0~jshint: Project@5.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle Project@5.0.0~jshint: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle Project@5.0.0~jshint: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/user/Documents/Git/Project/node_modules/.bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:/Users/user/npm/bin:/Users/user/npm/bin
9 verbose lifecycle Project@5.0.0~jshint: CWD: /Users/user/Documents/Git/Project
10 silly lifecycle Project@5.0.0~jshint: Args: [ '-c',
10 silly lifecycle   'jshint --reporter=tasks/misc_tasks/jshint.js build/ --exclude build/libs/' ]
11 silly lifecycle Project@5.0.0~jshint: Returned: code: 2  signal: null
12 info lifecycle Project@5.0.0~jshint: Failed to exec jshint script
13 verbose stack Error: Project@5.0.0 jshint:`jshint --reporter=tasks/misc_tasks/jshint.js build/ --exclude build/libs/
`13 verbose stack Exit status 2
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid Project@5.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/user/Documents/Git/Project
16 verbose Darwin 18.2.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "jshint"
18 verbose node v10.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 2
22 error Project@5.0.0 jshint:`jshint --reporter=tasks/misc_tasks/jshint.js build/ --exclude build/libs/
`22 error Exit status 2
23 error Failed at the Project@5.0.0 jshint script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 2, true ]`